# Rows being combined when using striping function in kableextra

Tags: r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I am loading a csv file into an R script and then printing that CSV with no edits to the file using kable in Rmarkdown. When I print the dataframe using the striping code, there is error in the striping pattern.  I was curious why this error may occur and what can fix it? I have attached a photo to show the stripping error that is happening (columns 1:2, rows 1:2).

[image: Striping Error]

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing your code or the csv file, but this works for me without glitches in the striping.

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
dt=read_csv("file.csv", col_names=FALSE)
kable(dt, col.names=NULL) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options="striped", stripe_index=seq(0,2,by=2)) %>% 
  column_spec(3, width="10cm")
```

[image]